# Bean with same name in Root and Child Application Context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

If I create bean with same name in Root Application context and Child Application context 
(**as in Root Application Context and dispatcher servlet context**) 
will child application context override the bean definition ? 
What will be the behavior please explain ? 
Also explain what will be the behavior In Java Config if I include other Configuration Class and both contain bean with same name. 
 
Will two beans be created ? Or one will override the other.

Comment: Boy, this seems like an excellent candidate for experimentation! Why not try it out and let us know the results?

Answer (score 1):

As per my Experimentation

In the parent and child Application Context new Bean is created for each Application Context **irrespective whether Bean name is same or not**. 
Any call made from ( autowired by ) **parent application context refers to Bean in Parent Application Context**. 
Any call made from ( autowired by ) **child application context refers to Bean in Child Application Context**.

**And In Java Config** importing other configuration which contains bean with same name does not create a new Bean and Bean Definition is Overridden.
**This effect is same as Importing bean of same name from XML.**